# Reformat selected code in strings in phpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

We know that there is a way to reformat and rearrange codes via **Ctrl+ alt + l** in **phpStorm** and it works fine.

But this ability can not reformat codes in a simple String(codes that are surrounded by single or double quotes).

For example this code is to run a select Query on DB :

```
$getPro = $db->Query("select products.`product_id`,products.`pro_title`, products.`pro_quantity`,products.`new_price`,products.`addedPrice`,products.`discount`, product_pics.`pic_name`
                    from `products` left join `product_pics` on `product_pics`.`product_id` = products.`product_id`
                    where products.`product_id`=:p_id limit 1", array (':p_id' => $p_id));
```

and i want to reformat this code to bellow one on pressing **Ctrl+ alt + l** or Any other way:

```
$getPro = $db->Query("SELECT
      products.`product_id`,
      products.`pro_title`,
      products.`pro_quantity`,
      products.`new_price`,
      products.`addedPrice`,
      products.`discount`,
      product_pics.`pic_name`
    FROM `products`
      LEFT JOIN `product_pics` ON `product_pics`.`product_id` = products.`product_id`
    WHERE products.`product_id` = :p_id
    LIMIT 1
", array (':p_id' => $p_id));
```

Of course I realized that we can do this via copy SQL string in phpStorm MySQL **Console** (Ctrl+shift+f10) and then use Ctrl+ alt + l shortcut.

What is the solution in your opinion?

**Edit:**
according to **LazyOne** comment, this is a screenshot of my code when pressing Alt+Enter . But there is no **Edit MySQL Fragment** option.

[image]

Comment: `Alt+Enter | Edit MySQL Fragment` and Reformat there -- any better?

Comment: i can not found "Edit MySQL Fragment" option with *Alt + Enter*. As I found out the only way is to copy SQL to MySQL Console and press *Ctrl + Alt + l*.

Comment: So what menu do you see when you Alt+Enter while having caret inside such string. Post screenshot of that code anyway (preferably using Default or Darcula color scheme)

Comment: @LazyOne  i add a Screenshot

Comment: 1) What is your IDE version? 2) If you choose "Change dialect to" and change it to MySQL -- will it be any better? 3) This is what I see in 9.5 EAP in WordPress site with no dialect setup: http://imgur.com/taZy0f1 -- the file is part of the project (not a Scratch file or anything like that)

Comment: @LazyOne - what you said worked for me (Alt+Enter, Edit MySQL Fragment, then CTRL+ALT+L). Thanks. But why doesn't that work when I am trying to reformat the whole script? (using CTRL+ALT+L when just editing the php code)

Comment: @hellohellosharp Because that's a different (injected) language fragment .. which could be incomplete ... or you may have formatted it in a special way. I, personally, like current behaviour; others may not. The Issue Tracker where Feature Request ticket can be created (if does not exist already) is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI